# Access 2007 OutputTo PDF Different from Printed Output

Tags: ms-access, pdf, printing

Using Access 2007 SP3, I have a report.  When printed to a printer, and in the print preview, the report looks fine.  Well within margins, proper output, no extra pages...everything is fine.

When outputting this same report to a PDF, the report appears zoomed, and the content is clipped.  No extra pages are printed as if I've gone beyond the margins.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport rptName, acViewPreview
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, PDFFileName, False
DoCmd.Close acReport, rptName
```

The report is opened in preview mode first so the page events fire to show/hide objects based on fields in the recordset that feeds the report.

I've tried both screen quality and print quality parameters in the OutputTo call, with the same results.  Also, even if I call OutputTo all on one line and the events don't fire, the report is still zoomed/clipped, it just has all the extra objects not hidden.

I've tried this on two different machines, one running Windows 7 and one running Windows Server 2008.

Even when setting a break point on the OutputTo line, the preview looks just fine...it's the resulting PDF file that doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only things I can think of are:

Try saving the report directly, without opening it first, so just replace your 3 lines of `DoCmd` by a single one:

```
   DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, rptName, acFormatPDF, PDFFileName, False
```

Also make sure that your report will fit into the page and that its properties allows it to be rescaled.
For instance, here are the settings I use for a report that I save to PDF directly with the same `DoCmd.OutputTo` as above.

[image: Report Properties]

Comment: When you've been staring at something for a long time, it's so easy to miss the little things.  The "Fit to Page" setting was "No" on my report. Changing that solved my issue.  Seems so obvious...now.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, but it was random. Usually corrected itself if I restarted my computer, but not this last time; still zoomed/clipped the document. Sure enough, I found the "Fit to Page" property was set to "NO". Changed to yes, and fixed problem. I'm still not sure why it worked sometimes and not others.